# Java server socket reading

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a very peculiar problem and my last resort was asking this on StackOverflow, so please be open minded!

Here are two programs:

A. Client: A java client running on an Android phone.
B. Server: A java server running on a Computer.

Here is what the two programs do:

Client sends server coordinates (in string format) every 2 milliseconds (very fast), and the server must read all those coordinates that the client sends it. In order to achieve this (given that the server is located at 10.0.0.1 and is listening on port 54321), the server must have a socket via which it reads all the incoming info. And yes, it does receive all of the information, BUT, there is a catch!

Now that you have the background behind the story, here is the problem:

The client connects to the server and as soon as that happens,it starts sending coordinates (in string format) at an extremely fast rate. The server does get all the messages, but it does not stop reading unless the client has disconnected. What i need is for the server to read every single message individually as they received!

Here is the code i used to read from the socket (this is for the server, and it is on its own thread):

```
    while(true) {
        try {
            BufferedReader socketReader = 
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String str = socketReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("New Message: " + str);
            socketReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Client disconnected
            System.out.println("Client disconnected.");
            break;
        }
    }
```

This is the output i am getting from the client (where x and y are numbers):

```
 New Message: x,yx,yx,yx,yx,yx,yx,yx,yx,yx,yx,yx,yx,yx,yx,yx,yx,y...and so on
```

And that text only shows up AFTER the client has disconnected. I want it to show up AS THE MESSAGES come in.

Just to clarify, this is the desired output:

```
 New Message: x,y
 New Message: x,y
 New Message: x,y
 New Message: x,y
 ... and so on
```

In case this is of any use, here is the method of writing to the socket (this code is from the client)

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
while(running) {
    writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    writer.write(x+","+y);
    writer.flush();
}
```

So all in all, what i need is for my server to read the messages as they come in instead of reading them all at the same time after the client disconnects. P.S in C# i have also written a server and that one reads the info as it comes in, but in Java this isnt working out!

Comment: Isn't there something wrong? It seems IOException happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling [readLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) which, as its name suggests, is for reading **lines**. Your data does not consist of lines.

If possible, change your protocol so that each set of coordinates is terminated by a newline and/or carriage return.

Unfortunately, I don't think you're going to be able to get this to work. 2ms resolution is just not possible over commodity network hardware and all kinds of things will break if you try to force it. If you enable Nagle, you'll get 200ms delays from Nagling when an ACK is late. If you disable Nagle, dropping a data packet will shoot your latency through the roof.

Honestly, I'd rip up the design and start over thinking through precisely what your requirements are and how you're going to meet them.

Where did you find an Android device that can send 500 packets a second?! No Wifi I know of can do that, and what use is GPS over a wire?

(If you're not already doing things like shrinking socket buffers to the absolute minimum, using non-blocking write operations, and handling partial writes by aborting and dropping partial data in the receiver, you won't get anywhere close to meeting your requirements. You *must not* let data back up if there's a momentary drop in connection bandwidth.)

Comment: +1 great idea (after my flush() idea, but he already thought of that)

Comment: Wow lol im going to try it if it works i will slap myself on the back many times. :D

Comment: Okay, so David you were correct, i added a "\r\n" to the messages. But i also had to get rid of the line "socketReader.close;". And allright, ill make it 60 packets a second. 60 frames per second is good enough any day. Thanks for all your brilliant input, much appreciated. BTW, I tried to disable Nagle by doing socket.noTcpDelay(true); is that correct? And i only did that on the client's code not on server's do i need to do that on both?

Comment: Does the server send any data back to the client ever? This affects whether ACKs can piggyback and the behavior of delayed ACK. If the server doesn't send anything, you may have to disable Nagle and shrink the socket buffer to as small as possible.

Comment: The problem is, data *will* back up in the socket buffer. And then the server will be lagging behind the client. (I presume that's undesirable. Is that correct?)

Comment: umm, so how do i exactly minimize the buffer and disable nagle? And no the server does not send anything back whatsoever. Thx for all the help

Comment: If the server sends nothing back, then there will be no ACK piggybacking (because there's no data for ACKs to piggyback on). That will make things much harder. Delayed ACK and Nagle will interact badly. Again, I say, "I'd rip up the design and start over thinking through precisely what your requirements are and how you're going to meet them". You're in a tight spot. If you don't disable Nagle, you'll have the delayed ACK problem. If you do, packet loss will lead to backup in the buffers and latency problems.

Comment: Also, I always get suspicious when we're working way outside the box to meet a crazy requirement and all of a sudden the requirement is *drastically* changed by a factor of 8. That suggests that I was never told the *real* requirements. I can't give you helpful advice if I don't know the **actual** requirements, what's just "nice to have" and so on. This is *not* a trivial task and needs to be thought out thoroughly. (Why not just have the server send a \r\n back?)

Comment: lol ok. This isnt some huge project and im only messing around with this stuff, but i dont think all that will be a problem for me because i already did it in C# and everything was silky smooth. All i wanted was for Java to be able to do the same thing so that has been done. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Do a `flush()` on your output socket in your client each time. The messages are actually being buffered until you close the socket now.

Comment: Yes, I have writer.flush(); on the client's code already. Thanks for the reply  anyway. Any other suggestions? I'll post the client's writing method too.